# How do i find the first duplicate value in a data frame based on time stamp in Python 3.x?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas

I am new to Python 3.6 and I have been trying to solve an assignment without any success using Pandas.

My dataframe looks like this:

```
Index  ID           Time              Account  Key   City    County 
 0      10     2016-01-01 12:30          11      55     a       NZ
 1      2      2016-01-02 13:30          14      34     b       AL
 2      33     2016-01-03 11:20          4       55     a       NZ
 3      4      2016-01-01 14:30          11      40     b       AL 
 4      18     2016-01-20 23:30          14      34     b       AL
 ..

100    41     2016-03-20 13:50          11      55     a       NZ
```

1. I want to identify that Account 11 and 14 are reoccurring and to count them in different buckets in a new column (Ie: occurring with changes in Key and occurring without changes in Key) but I want 11 to be counted once.
2. I want to calculate the time difference in hours between the first and second occurrence of Account 11 but to ignore all other occurrences of 11. The results should be placed in a new data frame with columns 'Account' and 'Time_diff'

Any ideas on how to proceed? I am using Spyder if that makes any difference =)

So for Q1 it would look like:

```
Index  ID           Time              Account  Key   City    County ChangeKey
 0      10     2016-01-01 12:30          11      55     a       NZ       0
 1      2      2016-01-02 13:30          14      34     b       AL       0
 2      33     2016-01-03 11:20          4       55     a       NZ       0
 3      4      2016-01-01 14:30          11      40     b       AL       1
 4      18     2016-01-20 23:30          14      34     b       AL       0
```

The key changes for account 11 but not account 14.

For Q2 the final result would look like

```
 Index        Time         Account  Timediff 
 0     2016-01-01 12:30    11         0      
 1     2016-01-02 13:30    14         0      
 2     2016-01-03 11:20    4          NA      
 3     2016-01-01 14:30    11         2      
 4     2016-01-20 23:30    14        320
```

Comment: Add your expected output here.

Comment: Ok cool! 
So for Q1 it would look like: